# User Profile Synchronization - How is deletion handled?

Tags: 2010, user-profile, synchronisation

I have an understanding of how to setup user profile synchronization but I am not sure how deletion from AD is handled in SharePoint... I understand the user's profile gets deleted as well as their mysite. How about contents created by users in other site collection within the farm? Does the content get deleted? If it stays, what value gets filled for the created/modified field?

Also items in workflow history list that is associated to the deleted user? Does that stay?

I have searched for resources in Google but haven't found anything that details the synchronization process. The following link goes into the deletion process but doesn't answer my questions:
http://www.harbar.net/archive/2011/02/10/account-deletion-and-sharepoint-2010-user-profile-synchronization.aspx

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood the sync will delete the user from SP profile database. As far as deleting that user's mysite, contents, wp is still a manual process.

Comment: Content does not get deleted for obvious reasons: there could be valuable data stored so deleting automatically would be bad... Same with user info: just because a user is deleted, he/she still was the original creator of the data so documents keep him/her as creator. The user also stays in the hidden user list on each site collection